# Is MacVim copy-to-clipboard supposed to be working on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac, vim, clipboard, osx-mavericks

I've recently found out that I can no longer copy text out of MacVim and paste into other Mac apps. I used to be able to do this on Mountain Lion.

I have the usual configurations set, namely:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

I have tried with a virgin, no configuration version of Vim with +clipboard set when building. It was built using Homebrew.

I have tried the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> combo, the `"+y` key combo, the `yy` combo, and others. Nothing seems to work.

The clipboard otherwise works fine for all other apps on the computer.

Am I experiencing an incompatibility that is new?

Comment: It works perfectly, here. Do you use the latest snapshot? How do you install it?

Comment: Works well for me too. Ver. 7.4 compiled by homebrew on 21/10/13.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I'll note that I also run vim inside of tmux.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I can't even copy & paste in MacVim with `set clipboard=unnamed`, the `*` register is not working and yanking into this register silently fails. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759289/vim-compiled-with-clipboard-but-both-and-registers-are-unable-to-store-yan

Comment: are you launching Vim from inside of tmux?  If so this is a known issue.  Fix is here: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue having `MacVim` installed and running `vim` in `Terminal.app`. It turns out that by default `MacVim` does not override system `vim` which hasn't clipboard support (`vim --version` prints `-clipboard`).

Reinstalling `MacVim`:

```
brew reinstall macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

and relaunching `Terminal.app` session solves the issue.